# OrderBy Coupons based on expiration status Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to display list of coupons and order it based on created_at date and expiration status.

The columns of my Coupons table

```
id
name
price
expired_at
created_at
status
```

My laravel query

```
$coupons= Coupon::where('status', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->orderBy( First I will need to compare expired_at with today date here)->get();
```

The problem is I dont know how to orderBy coupon_status, I want to display all expired coupons at bottom of the list and on-going coupons at top of the list and also orderBy created_at (the newest and on-going coupons is at the top of the list)

so probably need to create temporary column to get expiration status, before to order the list.
Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If you have any doubt in your query, try ->toSql() instead of ->get()

Comment: and what is `coupon_status`? are you storing `expired_at`?

Comment: coupon_status is not a column databse, its just if the coupon is already expired or not status based on today date, expired_at is expired date of the coupon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compare expired at with today (`expired_at < NOW()`)

```
$coupons= Coupon::where('status', 2)->orderByRaw(
 "CASE WHEN expired_at IS NULL OR expired_at > CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC"
);
```

Comment: I edited the question, coupon status will need to be compare first with today date, its not on db colum

Comment: the query is working but the ordered list is not correct, some expired coupons is still show above on-going coupon 
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->orderByRaw("CASE 
                WHEN expired_a< ".\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString()." THEN 0 
                WHEN expired_a IS NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 1 END DESC")

Comment: @TomKur  updated, if you use date data type you must use CURDATE() instead of Now()

Comment: its working, I dont know I cant use Carbon date, need to use CURDATE()

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ORDER BY coupon_status ASC, created_at DESC'`

This `expired_at` can compared with `CURDATE()`:

Try this query:

```php
$coupons= Coupon::where('status', 2)
                ->orderBy(\DB::raw('(IF((expired_at IS NULL OR expired_at < CURDATE()), 1, 0 )) ASC, created_at DESC'))
                ->get();
```

Comment: I edited the question, coupon status will need to be compare first with today date, its not on db column

Comment: The query I am using CASE WHEN
->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN expired_a< ".\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString()." THEN 0 WHEN expired_a IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 1 END DESC, created_at DESC") 
-- The list order is not correct, some expired coupons still showing above ongoing coupons

Comment: @TomKur is your expired_at is datetime or date?

Comment: expired_at is date only and NULL means there is no expiration date, it will be ongoing coupons

Answer (score 1):

You can also write like this:

```
$coupons= Coupon::where('status', 2)->orderBy([ 'coupon_status' => 'ASC', 'created_at' => 'DESC' ])->get();
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: I edited the question, coupon status will need to be compare first with today date, its not on db colum

Comment: $coupons= Coupon::whereDate('expired_at', Carbon::today())->where('status', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get(); please try with this? i hope it will help you